# Protractor - How to get the value of an Element that is changing too fast

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumber

I want to test a scenario.

I have a dropdown. I have added a class on it (to disable dropdown) while calling my API and remove the class after receiving the response.

I am trying to write a protractor test for it i.e. **Test that dropdown is disabled when we press submit button (which triggers API call)**

For Testing proposes I am not calling the actual API I am just calling mock response from JSON file.

**Problem Statement:**  Now issue is that class on dropdown removes sooo much fast that I cant test it.

```
  hasClass(element, className) {
    return element.getAttribute('class').then(function (classes) {
      return classes.split(' ').indexOf(className) !== -1;
    });
  }

   let disableClassPresent = hasClass(element(by.id('buttonId')), 'disableFilterDropdown') // Its should return true
        expect(disableClassPresent).to.be.equal(true);
```

How can solve this issue. If I add timeout in my code where I am calling mock response than it works fine because than DOMS finds the element before changing. I dont want to change my code how can I test it?

This is my HTML:

```
            <div style="width:24.5%;" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 padding-left-right-10">
                <label id="teamboard-title">{{translations.filter.teamboards}}</label>
                <div id="TeamboardDiv" [className]="disableTeamDropDown == true ? 'disableFilterDropdown' : ''">
                    <angular2-multiselect class="teamSelect" [attr.id]="teaamboardDropDownId"
                        [data]="teamboards" [(ngModel)]="selectedTeams" [settings]="dropdownSettingsTeams"
                        (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
                        (onSelectAll)="onSelectAllTeams($event)" (onDeSelectAll)="onDeselectAllTeams($event)"
                        (onFilterSelectAll)="onFilterSelectAll($event)"
                        (onFilterDeSelectAll)="onFilterDeSelectAll($event)">
                    </angular2-multiselect>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**disableFilterDropdown** this the class that is changing instantly.

Comment: Great question.  Can you add your own event listener to the page?  - listen to the state of the button so when the script changes the state to disabled it triggers a custom function which does something you can monitor e.g. trigger an alert - i've not done it  before but i can try and put something together if you need the support?

Comment: how about add sleep in calling mock response.

Comment: @yong it will slow down the execution.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options for you.

First one - potentially a really easy one. Add a delay to your mock. I know you say you don't want to do this - but consider adding the delay **for a specific input**. i.e. delay if your select value is a specific value created for this test or some value that isn't in your important/unit tests. If you deem this feature is important enough to automate then you should ensure your application has testability. If you don't you're spending a lot of time researching, asking questions on stack overflow, trialling answers and solving a problem that doesn't need to be a problem :-)

Second option is more complicated. You can weigh the effort of this against option 1.

You can use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to track when an element becomes disabled and use selenium/javascript to insert and trigger the required js code.

I don't have your angular page so I put this simple shell together:

```html
<select id="sel">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    
</select>
<br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('sel').disabled=true">disable select</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('sel').disabled=false">enable select</button>
<br>
<button onclick="activateObserver()">activate observer</button>
```

I think this loosely resembles what you say you have in your tests. A select that is disabled when you click the button.

1/
First thing to do is load in two pieces of js to run before you click the button.

Create the observer:

```html
<script>
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    for (var i=0, mutation; mutation = mutations[i]; i++) {
        if (mutation.attributeName == 'disabled') {
            if (mutation.target.disabled) {
                 alert('target disabled');
            } 
        }
    };
});
</script>
```

Create a function to activate the observer- please note that you'll need to update `document.getElementById('sel')` to be your SELECT element.

```html
<script>
function activateObserver(){observer.observe(document.getElementById('sel'), {attributes: true});}
</script>
```

Convert these to strings then load them in with selenium-webdriverjs using `driver.executescript(js)`.

2/
Then, execute the function `activateObserver`.

```
driver.ExecuteScript('activateObserver()');
```

3/
Next, click your submit button with selenium. I can't add code for this as you didn't share your DOM.

If all goes to plan you'll get an alert telling you the select was disabled. I'm pressing my the `disable select` button to trigger this (but the alert lives in the observer):

[image: alert from mutation]

4/
Finally - your assertion does **not** need to be that the `select` was `disabled` as I expect the moment you clear the alert the select will be re-enabled (as your mock will returned it's result).

It can now be that the `alert` `ispresent` - because the mutationobserver has confirmed this was triggered for you.

Comment: second option is quite long and I am using angular multiselect dropdown. It loads dynamically and if go for option one than how to add delay properly in mock response because if I add a timeout there than I am not able to perform next operation as protractor gets busy till next step executes. I have updated my question.

Comment: Hi @Mishi - What's your code for the mock? what mocking framework are you using? ... It might also be worth us being on the same page with language: Are you using a mock (such as mockito or moq) or have you create a network stub? - if you're testing for the GUI, and this is a test your automating in order to run forever, I assume you mean the latter? - and if not, for the GUI tests that will be needed in non-integrated environments have you considered creating a stub instead?

Comment: I am using protractor with cucumber in angular 6. For mocking I am have created a service that returns json file response instead of actual API response. I did the code changes in case of mock environment, I have added the timeout so I am able to catch the class but its sort of a workaround.